# Django reset oneToOneField on Custom User Model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, one-to-one

I have a custom User model, which has a one-to-one relationship with a UserProfile model. I want to create a new UserProfile object and switch the existing related UserProfile object with the newly created one.

This is essentially what I am trying to do:

```
    **views.py**
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        club = serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)

        user = self.request.user
        user.current_userprofile = None
        user.save()

        UserProfile.objects.create(
            user_account=self.request.user, 
            club=club, 
            current_active_userprofile=self.request.user, 
            is_admin=True
        )
```

```
    **models.py**
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user_account = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, related_name='userprofiles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        club = models.ForeignKey(Club, related_name='club_userprofiles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        current_active_userprofile = models.OneToOneField(UserAccount, related_name='current_userprofile', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

However, the perform_create method triggers an integrity error:

> UNIQUE constraint failed:
> userprofile_userprofile.current_active_userprofile_id

How do I reset the field to NULL so that I can connect it to the newly created object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `current_active_userprofile` to `None` with:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    club = serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)

    user = self.request.user
    current_profile = user.current_userprofile
    current_profile.current_active_userprofile = None
    current_profile.save()
    user.save()

    UserProfile.objects.create(
        user_account=self.request.user, 
        club=club, 
        current_active_userprofile=self.request.user, 
        is_admin=True
    )
```